# Knowing how to upgrade my pc hardware

Tags: memory, hardware-rec

I want to add more memory to my pc.
is there any tool that can scan my hardware tell me how much more memory i can fit, from which type (ddr2/3) in which slot?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ya, the tool is your eyes. They should have a look at the mobo manual which came with your mobo. It lists all of the memory configurations officially supported.

Answer (score 0):

Crucial have a system scanner app that will tell you what your machine will support. Kingston & Corsair both have structures to find by make & model etc.

[Crucial](http://www.crucial.com)
[Kingston](http://www.kingston.com/us/memory/search/options/)
[Corsair](http://www.corsair.com/en-gb/memory-finder)